# "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lui"

Tags: gcc

I was trying to compile my code when I encountered the below error.
I am trying to compile with cmake.

I searched the forum for similar errors.. But I couldn't find for specific below error. 
I found other library issues in the forum questions.

Error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lui
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmodelcommands
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmodel
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I tried to install "sudo apt-get install lib32z1-dev". But no solution. I got "lmodelcommands & lmodel" errors in addition.

If anyone has faced similar errors, please suggest me a solution.

Makefile Contains:

```
# CMAKE generated file: DO NOT EDIT!
# Generated by "Unix Makefiles" Generator, CMake Version 2.8

# Default target executed when no arguments are given to make.
default_target: all
.PHONY : default_target

#=============================================================================
# Special targets provided by cmake.

# Disable implicit rules so canoncical targets will work.
.SUFFIXES:

# Remove some rules from gmake that .SUFFIXES does not remove.
SUFFIXES =

.SUFFIXES: .hpux_make_needs_suffix_list

# Suppress display of executed commands.
$(VERBOSE).SILENT:

# A target that is always out of date.
cmake_force:
.PHONY : cmake_force

#=============================================================================
# Set environment variables for the build.

# The shell in which to execute make rules.
SHELL = /bin/sh

# The CMake executable.
CMAKE_COMMAND = /usr/bin/cmake

# The command to remove a file.
RM = /usr/bin/cmake -E remove -f

# The program to use to edit the cache.
CMAKE_EDIT_COMMAND = /usr/bin/ccmake

# The top-level source directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR = /home/pvadhana/Desktop/stpproject

# The top-level build directory on which CMake was run.
CMAKE_BINARY_DIR = /home/pvadhana/Desktop/stpproject/build

#=============================================================================
# Targets provided globally by CMake.

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake cache editor..."
    /usr/bin/ccmake -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : edit_cache

# Special rule for the target edit_cache
edit_cache/fast: edit_cache
.PHONY : edit_cache/fast

# Special rule for the target install
install: preinstall
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Install the project..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install

# Special rule for the target install
install/fast: preinstall/fast
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Install the project..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install/fast

# Special rule for the target install/local
install/local: preinstall
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Installing only the local directory..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LOCAL_ONLY=1 -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install/local

# Special rule for the target install/local
install/local/fast: install/local
.PHONY : install/local/fast

# Special rule for the target install/strip
install/strip: preinstall
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Installing the project stripped..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_DO_STRIP=1 -P cmake_install.cmake
.PHONY : install/strip

# Special rule for the target install/strip
install/strip/fast: install/strip
.PHONY : install/strip/fast

# Special rule for the target list_install_components
list_install_components:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Available install components are: \"Unspecified\""
.PHONY : list_install_components

# Special rule for the target list_install_components
list_install_components/fast: list_install_components
.PHONY : list_install_components/fast

# Special rule for the target package
package: preinstall
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Run CPack packaging tool..."
    /usr/bin/cpack --config ./CPackConfig.cmake
.PHONY : package

# Special rule for the target package
package/fast: package
.PHONY : package/fast

# Special rule for the target package_source
package_source:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Run CPack packaging tool for source..."
    /usr/bin/cpack --config ./CPackSourceConfig.cmake /home/pvadhana/Desktop/stpproject/build/CPackSourceConfig.cmake
.PHONY : package_source

# Special rule for the target package_source
package_source/fast: package_source
.PHONY : package_source/fast

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running CMake to regenerate build system..."
    /usr/bin/cmake -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR)
.PHONY : rebuild_cache

# Special rule for the target rebuild_cache
rebuild_cache/fast: rebuild_cache
.PHONY : rebuild_cache/fast

# Special rule for the target test
test:
    @$(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_echo_color --switch=$(COLOR) --cyan "Running tests..."
    /usr/bin/ctest --force-new-ctest-process $(ARGS)
.PHONY : test

# Special rule for the target test
test/fast: test
.PHONY : test/fast

# The main all target
all: cmake_check_build_system
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/pvadhana/Desktop/stpproject/build/CMakeFiles /home/pvadhana/Desktop/stpproject/build/CMakeFiles/progress.marks
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 all
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -E cmake_progress_start /home/pvadhana/Desktop/stpproject/build/CMakeFiles 0
.PHONY : all

# The main clean target
clean:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 clean
.PHONY : clean

# The main clean target
clean/fast: clean
.PHONY : clean/fast

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall: all
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall

# Prepare targets for installation.
preinstall/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 preinstall
.PHONY : preinstall/fast

# clear depends
depend:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 1
.PHONY : depend

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named Continuous

# Build rule for target.
Continuous: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 Continuous
.PHONY : Continuous

# fast build rule for target.
Continuous/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Continuous.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Continuous.dir/build
.PHONY : Continuous/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named ContinuousBuild

# Build rule for target.
ContinuousBuild: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 ContinuousBuild
.PHONY : ContinuousBuild

# fast build rule for target.
ContinuousBuild/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/ContinuousBuild.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/ContinuousBuild.dir/build
.PHONY : ContinuousBuild/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named ContinuousConfigure

# Build rule for target.
ContinuousConfigure: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 ContinuousConfigure
.PHONY : ContinuousConfigure

# fast build rule for target.
ContinuousConfigure/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/ContinuousConfigure.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/ContinuousConfigure.dir/build
.PHONY : ContinuousConfigure/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named ContinuousCoverage

# Build rule for target.
ContinuousCoverage: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 ContinuousCoverage
.PHONY : ContinuousCoverage

# fast build rule for target.
ContinuousCoverage/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/ContinuousCoverage.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/ContinuousCoverage.dir/build
.PHONY : ContinuousCoverage/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named ContinuousMemCheck

# Build rule for target.
ContinuousMemCheck: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 ContinuousMemCheck
.PHONY : ContinuousMemCheck

# fast build rule for target.
ContinuousMemCheck/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/ContinuousMemCheck.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/ContinuousMemCheck.dir/build
.PHONY : ContinuousMemCheck/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named ContinuousStart

# Build rule for target.
ContinuousStart: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 ContinuousStart
.PHONY : ContinuousStart

# fast build rule for target.
ContinuousStart/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/ContinuousStart.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/ContinuousStart.dir/build
.PHONY : ContinuousStart/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named ContinuousSubmit

# Build rule for target.
ContinuousSubmit: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 ContinuousSubmit
.PHONY : ContinuousSubmit

# fast build rule for target.
ContinuousSubmit/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/ContinuousSubmit.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/ContinuousSubmit.dir/build
.PHONY : ContinuousSubmit/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named ContinuousTest

# Build rule for target.
ContinuousTest: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 ContinuousTest
.PHONY : ContinuousTest

# fast build rule for target.
ContinuousTest/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/ContinuousTest.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/ContinuousTest.dir/build
.PHONY : ContinuousTest/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named ContinuousUpdate

# Build rule for target.
ContinuousUpdate: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 ContinuousUpdate
.PHONY : ContinuousUpdate

# fast build rule for target.
ContinuousUpdate/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/ContinuousUpdate.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/ContinuousUpdate.dir/build
.PHONY : ContinuousUpdate/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named Experimental

# Build rule for target.
Experimental: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 Experimental
.PHONY : Experimental

# fast build rule for target.
Experimental/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Experimental.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Experimental.dir/build
.PHONY : Experimental/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named ExperimentalBuild

# Build rule for target.
ExperimentalBuild: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 ExperimentalBuild
.PHONY : ExperimentalBuild

# fast build rule for target.
ExperimentalBuild/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/ExperimentalBuild.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/ExperimentalBuild.dir/build
.PHONY : ExperimentalBuild/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named ExperimentalConfigure

# Build rule for target.
ExperimentalConfigure: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 ExperimentalConfigure
.PHONY : ExperimentalConfigure

# fast build rule for target.
ExperimentalConfigure/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/ExperimentalConfigure.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/ExperimentalConfigure.dir/build
.PHONY : ExperimentalConfigure/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named ExperimentalCoverage

# Build rule for target.
ExperimentalCoverage: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 ExperimentalCoverage
.PHONY : ExperimentalCoverage

# fast build rule for target.
ExperimentalCoverage/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/ExperimentalCoverage.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/ExperimentalCoverage.dir/build
.PHONY : ExperimentalCoverage/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named ExperimentalMemCheck

# Build rule for target.
ExperimentalMemCheck: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 ExperimentalMemCheck
.PHONY : ExperimentalMemCheck

# fast build rule for target.
ExperimentalMemCheck/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/ExperimentalMemCheck.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/ExperimentalMemCheck.dir/build
.PHONY : ExperimentalMemCheck/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named ExperimentalStart

# Build rule for target.
ExperimentalStart: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 ExperimentalStart
.PHONY : ExperimentalStart

# fast build rule for target.
ExperimentalStart/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/ExperimentalStart.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/ExperimentalStart.dir/build
.PHONY : ExperimentalStart/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named ExperimentalSubmit

# Build rule for target.
ExperimentalSubmit: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 ExperimentalSubmit
.PHONY : ExperimentalSubmit

# fast build rule for target.
ExperimentalSubmit/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/ExperimentalSubmit.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/ExperimentalSubmit.dir/build
.PHONY : ExperimentalSubmit/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named ExperimentalTest

# Build rule for target.
ExperimentalTest: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 ExperimentalTest
.PHONY : ExperimentalTest

# fast build rule for target.
ExperimentalTest/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/ExperimentalTest.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/ExperimentalTest.dir/build
.PHONY : ExperimentalTest/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named ExperimentalUpdate

# Build rule for target.
ExperimentalUpdate: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 ExperimentalUpdate
.PHONY : ExperimentalUpdate

# fast build rule for target.
ExperimentalUpdate/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/ExperimentalUpdate.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/ExperimentalUpdate.dir/build
.PHONY : ExperimentalUpdate/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named Nightly

# Build rule for target.
Nightly: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 Nightly
.PHONY : Nightly

# fast build rule for target.
Nightly/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Nightly.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/Nightly.dir/build
.PHONY : Nightly/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named NightlyBuild

# Build rule for target.
NightlyBuild: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 NightlyBuild
.PHONY : NightlyBuild

# fast build rule for target.
NightlyBuild/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/NightlyBuild.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/NightlyBuild.dir/build
.PHONY : NightlyBuild/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named NightlyConfigure

# Build rule for target.
NightlyConfigure: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 NightlyConfigure
.PHONY : NightlyConfigure

# fast build rule for target.
NightlyConfigure/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/NightlyConfigure.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/NightlyConfigure.dir/build
.PHONY : NightlyConfigure/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named NightlyCoverage

# Build rule for target.
NightlyCoverage: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 NightlyCoverage
.PHONY : NightlyCoverage

# fast build rule for target.
NightlyCoverage/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/NightlyCoverage.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/NightlyCoverage.dir/build
.PHONY : NightlyCoverage/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named NightlyMemCheck

# Build rule for target.
NightlyMemCheck: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 NightlyMemCheck
.PHONY : NightlyMemCheck

# fast build rule for target.
NightlyMemCheck/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/NightlyMemCheck.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/NightlyMemCheck.dir/build
.PHONY : NightlyMemCheck/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named NightlyMemoryCheck

# Build rule for target.
NightlyMemoryCheck: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 NightlyMemoryCheck
.PHONY : NightlyMemoryCheck

# fast build rule for target.
NightlyMemoryCheck/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/NightlyMemoryCheck.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/NightlyMemoryCheck.dir/build
.PHONY : NightlyMemoryCheck/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named NightlyStart

# Build rule for target.
NightlyStart: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 NightlyStart
.PHONY : NightlyStart

# fast build rule for target.
NightlyStart/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/NightlyStart.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/NightlyStart.dir/build
.PHONY : NightlyStart/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named NightlySubmit

# Build rule for target.
NightlySubmit: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 NightlySubmit
.PHONY : NightlySubmit

# fast build rule for target.
NightlySubmit/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/NightlySubmit.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/NightlySubmit.dir/build
.PHONY : NightlySubmit/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named NightlyTest

# Build rule for target.
NightlyTest: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 NightlyTest
.PHONY : NightlyTest

# fast build rule for target.
NightlyTest/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/NightlyTest.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/NightlyTest.dir/build
.PHONY : NightlyTest/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named NightlyUpdate

# Build rule for target.
NightlyUpdate: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 NightlyUpdate
.PHONY : NightlyUpdate

# fast build rule for target.
NightlyUpdate/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/NightlyUpdate.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/NightlyUpdate.dir/build
.PHONY : NightlyUpdate/fast

#=============================================================================
# Target rules for targets named stpproject

# Build rule for target.
stpproject: cmake_check_build_system
    $(MAKE) -f CMakeFiles/Makefile2 stpproject
.PHONY : stpproject

# fast build rule for target.
stpproject/fast:
    $(MAKE) -f source/CMakeFiles/stpproject.dir/build.make source/CMakeFiles/stpproject.dir/build
.PHONY : stpproject/fast

# Help Target
help:
    @echo "The following are some of the valid targets for this Makefile:"
    @echo "... all (the default if no target is provided)"
    @echo "... clean"
    @echo "... depend"
    @echo "... Continuous"
    @echo "... ContinuousBuild"
    @echo "... ContinuousConfigure"
    @echo "... ContinuousCoverage"
    @echo "... ContinuousMemCheck"
    @echo "... ContinuousStart"
    @echo "... ContinuousSubmit"
    @echo "... ContinuousTest"
    @echo "... ContinuousUpdate"
    @echo "... Experimental"
    @echo "... ExperimentalBuild"
    @echo "... ExperimentalConfigure"
    @echo "... ExperimentalCoverage"
    @echo "... ExperimentalMemCheck"
    @echo "... ExperimentalStart"
    @echo "... ExperimentalSubmit"
    @echo "... ExperimentalTest"
    @echo "... ExperimentalUpdate"
    @echo "... Nightly"
    @echo "... NightlyBuild"
    @echo "... NightlyConfigure"
    @echo "... NightlyCoverage"
    @echo "... NightlyMemCheck"
    @echo "... NightlyMemoryCheck"
    @echo "... NightlyStart"
    @echo "... NightlySubmit"
    @echo "... NightlyTest"
    @echo "... NightlyUpdate"
    @echo "... edit_cache"
    @echo "... install"
    @echo "... install/local"
    @echo "... install/strip"
    @echo "... list_install_components"
    @echo "... package"
    @echo "... package_source"
    @echo "... rebuild_cache"
    @echo "... test"
    @echo "... stpproject"
.PHONY : help



#=============================================================================
# Special targets to cleanup operation of make.

# Special rule to run CMake to check the build system integrity.
# No rule that depends on this can have commands that come from listfiles
# because they might be regenerated.
cmake_check_build_system:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
.PHONY : cmake_check_build_system
```

==================================================

CMakeCCompiler.cmake file contains:

```
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/gcc")
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ARG1 "")
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID "GNU")
SET(CMAKE_C_PLATFORM_ID "Linux")

SET(CMAKE_AR "/usr/bin/ar")
SET(CMAKE_RANLIB "/usr/bin/ranlib")
SET(CMAKE_LINKER "/usr/bin/ld")
SET(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCC 1)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_LOADED 1)
SET(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_MINGW )
SET(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_CYGWIN )
IF(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_CYGWIN)
  SET(CYGWIN 1)
  SET(UNIX 1)
ENDIF(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_CYGWIN)

SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ENV_VAR "CC")

IF(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_MINGW)
  SET(MINGW 1)
ENDIF(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_MINGW)
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ID_RUN 1)
SET(CMAKE_C_SOURCE_FILE_EXTENSIONS c)
SET(CMAKE_C_IGNORE_EXTENSIONS h;H;o;O;obj;OBJ;def;DEF;rc;RC)
SET(CMAKE_C_LINKER_PREFERENCE 10)

# Save compiler ABI information.
SET(CMAKE_C_SIZEOF_DATA_PTR "")
SET(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ABI "")

IF(CMAKE_C_SIZEOF_DATA_PTR)
  SET(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P "${CMAKE_C_SIZEOF_DATA_PTR}")
ENDIF(CMAKE_C_SIZEOF_DATA_PTR)

IF(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ABI)
  SET(CMAKE_INTERNAL_PLATFORM_ABI "${CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ABI}")
ENDIF(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ABI)

SET(CMAKE_C_HAS_ISYSROOT "")


SET(CMAKE_C_IMPLICIT_LINK_LIBRARIES "")
SET(CMAKE_C_IMPLICIT_LINK_DIRECTORIES "")
```

==================================================================

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct name for the library? Also, may consider checking the the library is in your system path.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Actually I am not sure how to find the name of the library for the error shown. I browsed through the forum and got the name "lib32z1-dev". Can you tell me how to find the suited library for the errors shown.

Comment: It might be helpful if you could paste the Makefile or command line invocation you use to compile your program. Are you sure libui.so, libmodelcommands.so and libmodel.so are actual libraries that you have installed? That's what ld tries to link your program with.

Comment: I have the edited my initial question with the Makefile contents.